# how to get a "google image search" like layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i am trying to build a UI that is similar to that of the Google image search,
basically a bottomless grid of pictures that are dynamically fetched once the user scrolls down.

i cant use the choose image intent because the pictures are not on the users device.

my current thinking is using a grid-layout and adding more items each time the user scrolls all the way down, does something like this already exists?
or is the grid-layout design is the way to go?
[image: google image search]

Comment: Check this article http://java.dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android-1

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking, you should post this as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use existing libraries that make use of `GridView`. Check out the following [article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android-1).

Just in case this article disappear I will post links to mentioned libraries here:

- https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid
- https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView

There are probably more libraries out there.